# Network Render quality settings

Tags: rendering, network

Hopefully this is a simple question..
Ive just set up a small render farm with the "network render" plugin but I cant seem to change the render quality ... all the render options (samples, dimensions etc) are no longer visible .. Im a bit of a newbie to Blender so Im hoping I missing something simple..  thanks heaps in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

ok.. (posting this in case it helps someone else) 
I think I figured it out..  change renderer back to cycles.. 
adjust render settings.. (and save) .. then choose network render again .. 
Cant say for sure as my file is still rendering but going by the time each frame is taking its looking promising..